# Batch convert Excel to text-delimited files

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm facing a problem on dealing with converting Excel spreadsheets to txt files.

What I want to do is to create a Macro which can takes all the xls files in one folder and convert them to txt files.

The code currently working on

```
Sub Combined()

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\A9993846\Desktop\"
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim sName As String
  Dim inputString As String

  With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  sName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")

  Do Until sName = ""
    With GetObject(fPath & sName)
      For Each sh In .Worksheets
        With sh
          .SaveAs Replace(sName, ".xls*", ".txt"), 42 'UPDATE:
        End With
      Next sh
      .Close True
    End With
    sName = Dir
  Loop

  With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
End Sub
```

But It's not working as expected, I have 0 knowledge on VB. Anyone willing to give a hand?

Comment: How exactly is it "not working as expected"? What results do you get, and how do they differ from the results you expect?

Comment: Err, the line .SaveAs Replace(sName, ".xls*", ".txt"), 42 'UPDATE:
are causing the error of Run-time error '1004'. After replacing with sh.SaveAs ePath & sName + sh.Name + ".txt", xlTextWindows, everything works fine. But really apperciate for your kind help!

Comment: BTW ePath is the new path where I want to place the files defined as Const ePath As String = "C:\Users\A9993846\Desktop\Test\"

Comment: @HeLi added code to do the job for you. Related to 1004 your path info is probably wrong and this is why .SaveAs doesn't work. If you want to keep your code and go "your way" try to replace .SaveAs with MsgBox to see if path info is correct (it won't be :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below converts all Excel Workbooks (tests file extension for "xlsx") in a given folder into CSV files. File names will be [workbookname][sheetname].csv, ie "foo.xlsx" will get "foo.xlsxSheet1.scv", "foo.xlsxSheet2.scv", etc. In order to run it, create a plain text file, rename it to .vbs and copy-paste the code below. Change path info and run it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, myFolder
Dim xlCSV

myFolder="C:\your\path\to\excelfiles\"


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xlCSV = 6 'Excel CSV format enum
Call ConvertAllExcelFiles(myFolder)
Set oFSO = Nothing

Call MsgBox ("Done!")


Sub ConvertAllExcelFiles(ByVal oFolder)
Dim targetF, oFileList, oFile
Dim oExcel, oWB, oWSH

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set targetF = oFSO.GetFolder(oFolder)
    Set oFileList = targetF.Files
    For Each oFile in oFileList
        If (Right(oFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx") Then
            Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
            For Each oWSH in oWB.Sheets
                Call oWSH.SaveAs (oFile.Path & oWSH.Name & ".csv", xlCSV)
            Next
            Set oWSH = Nothing
            Call oWB.Close
            Set oWB = Nothing
        End If
    Next
    Call oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can give better file naming, error handling/etc if needed.

Comment: Hi mark, your way is also a very convenient way handling such an issue, thanks for helping out.

Comment: This isn't VBA. Stop mixing VBScript with VBA, how can this be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you define `sPath` as a path containing wildcard characters:

```
sName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")
```

and replace only the extension portion (`.xls*`), but leave the wildcard character before the extension in place:

```
Replace(sName, ".xls*", ".txt")
```

This produces the following path:

```
C:\Users\A9993846\Desktop\*.txt
```

which causes the error you observed, because the `SaveAs` method tries to save the spreadsheet to a file with the literal name `*.txt`, but `*` is not a valid character for file names.

Replace this:

```
.SaveAs Replace(sName, ".xls*", ".txt"), 42
```

with this:

```
Set wb = sh.Parent
basename = Replace(wb.FullName, Mid(wb.Name, InStrRev(wb.Name, ".")), "")
.SaveAs basename & "_" & sh.Name & ".txt", xlUnicodeText
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar thanks for your reply, I tried out but new bugs emerged:sh.FullName gives me a Compile error:Method or data member not found

Comment: My mistake. `sh` is a reference to a worksheet, so you need to get a reference to the parent object (the workbook) first. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi Ansgar I think your solution saves only current workbook but missed individual worksheets. This goes away from my purpose of save each sheet in a different format. But thanks anyway

Comment: It didn't miss sheets, but overwrote each saved sheet with the next one, so that only the last sheet remained. Fixed by appending the sheet name to the workbook name.