# Converting Excel files to Text using Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, format-conversion

I am trying to save every .xls file in a folder location as text using Access VBA. I have patched together the code below. However, it only successfully saves the 1st excel file as text and then it seems to hang.

I have reviewed this post which I think achieves something similar to what I want: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141885/batch-convert-excel-to-text-delimited-files) .But I have been at this for so long that nothing is making sense!! Any ideas? Is it getting stuck on `ActiveWorkbook.Close`?

```
 Public Sub FormatAsText()
Dim myfile As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB1 As Excel.Workbook

Dim objFso As FileSystemObject
Dim strPath As String
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objFile As File

        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        strPath = "C:FolderLocation..."

        Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

        myfile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls")

            For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
                If objFile.Name Like "*.xls" Then
                    Workbooks.Open objFile, ReadOnly:=False
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=strPath & "\" & Replace(myfile, ".xls", ".txt"), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
                End If
            Next objFile

        Debug.Print myfile

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB1 = Nothing

Set objFso = Nothing

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Add  `xlApp.Visible = True` after `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application`.  When you run the code with that change, is there any information displayed in Excel which explains the problem?

Comment: Thanks HansUp. After doing that, I can see that it opens the 1st excel file, saves it as text, then closes the excel file. Next, it opens the 2nd second file, formats it as text but tries to save it with the same name as the 1st text file. ("A file already exists ... Do you want to replace it?"). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `xlApp.Visible = True` after `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application` you discovered Excel is waiting for you to tell it whether to overwrite an existing file which has the same name as the one you're trying to save.

That happens because you assign a value to *myfile* just once ...

```vb
myfile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls")
```

... but then re-use that same name as the basis for generating the name of each *.txt* file you attempt to save ...

```vb
FileName:=strPath & "\" & Replace(myfile, ".xls", ".txt")
```

I think you can just substitute *objFile.Name* there because it should match the name of the current workbook file ... which means your *.txt* file name will be different each time through the `For Each` loop.

```vb
FileName:=strPath & "\" & Replace(objFile.Name, ".xls", ".txt")
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks! That sorted it. One last thing though - im still being prompted to 'save' each file. Ive been playing around with Do.CmdSetWarnings False. Does it matter where in the code I insert that?

Comment: Where do you get that prompt?  At `ActiveWorkbook.Close`?  If so, use `ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False`  I would never recommend anyone use `Do.CmdSetWarnings False`